# Best and Average running time of a merge sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time, merge, complexity-theory

How do I explain why the best running time of a merge sort algorithm is Big Omega (n log n) and the average running time is Big theta (n log n)?

Answer (score 0):

Lower order terms and/or constant factors are ignored for Big Omega, and normally Big Omega is used to describe the upper bound or worst case scenario. Big Theta should be a lower and upper bound and/or qualified as best case, average case, worst case, specific case.

For a pure merge sort (not a hybrid that uses some type of sort on smaller groups), the number of moves is the same, n ⌈ log2(n) ⌉  (where ⌈⌉ is integer ceiling), while the number of compares can vary, worst case a bit less than n ⌈ log2(n) ⌉ and best case about 1/2 of that, so only a difference in the constant factor. If the dataset elements fit in a register (like sorting an array of integers), the compare time may be hidden by the memory access time (the compares have little or no effect on the overall time). If doing an external merge sort (such as sorting large files), the compare time may be hidden by the device read / write time.

Wiki articles:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms